# looping with indexOf to remove html entities

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I do this with jquery? I thought of loop and indexOf but can't get there yet. I want to delete all the node after the `[` symbol.

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>[</p><!-- detect this symbol and delete ALL the element after it (include itself) -->
<p>a</p>
<p>b</p>
<p>c</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
```

Comment: what part of your code is not working ?

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how you can ask a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use jQuery [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to select element with specific text. Try this:

Till jQuery 1.8:

```
$("p:contains('[')").nextAll().andSelf().remove();
```

With jQuery newer versions:

```
$("p:contains('[')").nextAll().addBack().remove();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/b8n47e18/)**

Comment: +1 but `andSelf` is deprecated since 1.8, it's called `addBack` now.

Comment: @elclanrs: Mybad. Thanks Bro. Updated :)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you mentioned something about indexOf, so here is a long way procedural way of doing this using JQuery:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k8mzaynq/1/)

```
var remove = false;
var para = {};
$("p").each(function () {
    para = $(this);
    if (para.text().indexOf("[") !=-1) {
        remove = true;
    }
    if (remove) {
        para.remove();
    }  
});
```

Maybe you can wrap it up in a function

```
function remove_elem(elem, ch) {
    var to_remove = false;
    var para = {};
    $("" + elem).each(function () {
        para = $(this);
        if (para.text().indexOf("" + ch) != -1) {
            to_remove = true;
        }
        if (to_remove) {
            para.remove();
        }
    });    
    return to_remove;
}
//And call it 
remove_elem("p", "[");
```